# How to create a card in HTML from a button with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, i have an HTML document with the following code and I'm trying to create other cards like this with a button:

```html
    <div id="card" class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">Mesa 1</h2>

            <div class="botao">
                <button id="registrarPedido" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target='#formModal'>Registrar Pedido</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="modal" id="formModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title">Registre o pedido</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="NumMesa" placeholder="Numero da mesa">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Pedido">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="number" placeholder="Quantidade de pessoas na mesa">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar pedido</button>
```

How do I create a button that creates another card like the one above?

Comment: I have made a few edits to (hopefully) improve the appearance/impact of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use clone();

https://api.jquery.com/clone/

something like this in your html

```
<button type="button" class="j-clone-card">Clone the card</button>
```

and in jquery

```
$('.j-clone-card').click(function(){
 $(this).closest('.card').clone();

})
```

For clone the card, I don´t know if is the result expected